# The problem of for loop iteration updation in python

Tags: python

I face this problem anytime I try to update the value of the iterator variable of the python for a loop. It just does not let me update the variable.

```
  for i in range(1,10):
      print(i)
      i=i+5
      print(i)

    The output turn out to be:
   1
   6
   2
   7
   3
   8
   4
   9
   5
   10
   6
   11
   7
   12
   8
   13
   9
   14
```

Can anyone give me the explanation of this output and solution to my problem if I want to update the iterator variable?

Comment: You are updating `i` alright. But `i` does not update the `range` iterator. The iterator will assign a new value to `i` on each iteration. In general, you can't modify an iterator. You can only *skip* iterations.

Comment: Are you looking for `for i in range(1, 10, 5):`?

Comment: @deceze - Ohk , I encountered this problem while solving a problem, what could be the possible solution to this problem if for the certain value of ' i ', I want my iterator to jump ahead 5 values?

Comment: @Austin - Yes that could be done, but what if I want to update the value of iterator for some certain values, not everytime

Answer (score 0):

`range(1, 10)` is a range object( list if it is python 2 ). And each time for loop begins, elements are assigned into the `i` variable from that iterable object. And then the loop continues. Even if you update the value of `i` inside the for loop. It will be reassigned to the next element that is returned by the range object when the for loop starts again.

So I think what you need is a step parameter that skips 5 numbers. So you can try something like this.

`x = range(1, 10, 5)`, Where 5 is taken as the step parameter.

Comment: Hopefully we're talking Python 3 here, in which `range` returns a generator…

Comment: In Python 3 `range()` returns a `range` object, not a `list`, as in the old  Python 2 `xrange()` returned an `xrange` object.

Comment: Oh yes. In python 3 range is a range object and in Python 2 is a list. I'll edit that out thanks !

Comment: In python 2 you would use `xrange()` here, not `range()` *because* `range()` returns a list.

Comment: Oh, Thank you :). xrange isn't there in python 3 I suppose ?